# JS Dropbox API Account Secret

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am using the Dropbox Core API for a web application. On my server, I want to have a profile for each user, that is linked with his Dropbox account. How can I ensure, that only this user has access to his information? Can I get some sort of a secure unique Dropbox password hash for the Dropbox user?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could just store the profile in the user's Dropbox (e.g. via the Datastore API). Then you don't have to worry about it at all... only the authenticated user can see his or her own data.

Otherwise you could just use the user ID. If you're doing this server-side, pass the OAuth token to the server, and on the server call `/account/info` to get the user ID. Then just tie the profile to that user ID.